# Can't enter values into second element if two web elements are of same type

Tags: selenium, webdriver

How to distinguish between elements of same type, in this case, two password type elements while using Selenium Webdriver. In my application, I was not able to find elements by name or id. So I used `driver.switchTo().activeElement()`.

Now, there are two elements of password types in the html and when I try to access the second element, the value sent using `element2.sendKeys("007")` gets entered in `element1` field.

In other words, can't access the second element at all!

Comment: Can u paste the html code of it

Comment: <input name="userid" type="text" size="12" maxLength="12"/>

Comment: <input name="password" type="password" size="12" maxLength="100"/> <input name="logonKey" type="password" size="12" maxLength="8"/>   The problem here is when use switchTo().activeElement() method, I will only end up entering values in name=password field instead of entering the value in logonKey field. I tried findElement(By.name(userid)) ( for other elements as well) but the webdriver couldn't detect the element.

Comment: are those elements in iframe?

Comment: Then why are you using `.switchTo` at all? You shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findelements(By.name('userid'));
element.getindex("1").sendKeys("007");
List<WebElement> element = driver.findelements(By.name('password'));
element.getindex("1").sendKeys("007");
```